# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI

Tags: node.js, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, iisnode

I have installed the iisnode in windows server(Windows server 2008, IIS 7.5).I can check the sample application from iisnode. Samples are working fine.And also i created the application inside the C:\inetpub\iisnode\www\ folder. It's also working fine. But when i move my application into my domain it causes the problem. First it showed the error like

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler "iisnode" has a bad
>   module "iisnode" in its module list

For that i have changed the Enabled 32 bit application false.

After this i'm getting error like

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\isapi\urlprotect.dll" failed
>
> I installed the following version of node and iisnode IISNode:
>   iisnode-full-iis7-v0.2.2-x64 Node : node-v0.10.24-x64 Server : Windows
>   server 2008 IIS Version: IIS 7.5

My domain has been integrated with Parallels Panel 11.0. Please help any one how to solve this issue and run my node application for my domain.

Comment: did you find anything? same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because urlprotect.dll is 32 bit application, but iisnode is 64 bit.
You need either remove urlprotect.dll ISAPI Filter from IIS or install a 32 bit version of iisnode.